# Databricks connect test hangs indefinitely on "The system cannot find the path specified."

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I have followed the instructions on this page to install databricks-connect on Windows 10, Python 3.8, databricks version 9.1, to connect to Azure Databricks cluster:

https://towardsdatascience.com/get-started-spark-with-databricks-and-pyspark-72572179bd03

When I run:

```
databricks-connect test
```

I get this error:

```
* PySpark is installed at C:\Users\brend\miniconda3\envs\try-databricks-7.3\lib\site-packages\pyspark
* Checking SPARK_HOME
* Checking java version
java version "1.8.0_311"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_311-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.311-b11, mixed mode)
* Skipping scala command test on Windows
* Testing python command
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

and it hangs indefinitely. Further investigation shows it is hanging inside the call to spark-submit.cmd  (hence the call to spark-submit2.cmd).

I do not have any other Spark installation locally.

The problem has been replicated on databricks 7.3 and 9.1

What can I do to diagnose the problem further?

Answer (score 2):

I hit this error because I mistakenly appended `\bin` at the end of the path of JAVA_HOME environment variable after installing Java SE. The correct JAVA_HOME should be something like `C:\java\Java\jre1.8.0_321`, to which the Spark scripts will append `\bin` on their own.

To find whether this is true for you or not, you need to add print statements to a couple of scripts to see which program is Windows unable to find in your script.

Start with this:

As per your command output, go to folder `C:\Users\brend\miniconda3\envs\try-databricks-7.3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\bin` and open the script `spark-submit2.cmd` in a text editor. The first line says `@echo off`. Underneath this line, add a new line saying `@echo on`. Run your `databricks-connect test` again and see what is the very last command printed on the screen before it fails.

In my case, I saw that the script was calling a bunch of other scripts, which eventually called `C:\java\Java\jre1.8.0_321\bin\bin\java`, which led to Windows being unable to find Java.

Once you fix your error, feel free to delete all the `@echo on` statements that you added.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the environment variable `SPARK_HOME` and try setting that to the  path obtained with `databricks-connect get-jar-dir`, excluding the trailing "/jars".